# Filtering by Date and changing measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I'm trying to build a report in a table that returns a count of completed checklists that are filtered by 2 Date Intelligence slicers. I have the targets for that month in a table, but I'm not sure how to change the measure by what's selected in the slicer.

I would like the measure to return the Target.Monthname of the selected slicers from the table Targets. The slicer is based on the DonesafeFolder Table with "Date of Completion"

[image]

[image]

Comment: If each month is in a separate column, unpivot them.  You'll then have a single column with all the months listed (as well as your other data in other columns).  You can then create a slicer for just the month columns of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand.
But from your pictures, I think you should take a step back.
when using powerBI it is recommended to use a star schema, with facts and dimensions tables. Usually you model that when you import your data (with power query).

When using a star schema you also have a date dimension with the month on the rows instead of columns and powerBI is better at handling data structured like that. to lean about designing the data model you can read [MS's guide to star schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-bi/guidance/star-schema)

Of cause, if you know what you are doing, you can use your approach, but it makes things alot harder.

BTW. you can't access the values in the slicers/filters directly. they filters the column you select which are then passed to the measures you create. If your datamodel is sound they should indirectly filter your measure.